Has the breaker size rating changed since 1990
I have a home that was built in 1990.
I recently had an inspector say the breakers were oversized for the wire size on some circuits. i.e. 12 AWG solid copper wire and 30 amp breaker.
Was this change since the home was built?
Or did the electrician install an oversized breaker?

@Lundin, Oversized also potentially prevents the breaker tripping when the wire is catching things on fire...so probably not a good trade-off.

@Chris Knudsen, I cannot believe any electrician would install an oversize breaker for any reason.  The consequences for him individually and the company are far too great even extending to manslaughter if a death occured because a fire resulted as result of knowingly installing an improper breaker.  20 amp breakers are readily available and relatively cheap, heck you can buy them at Walmart.

@RMDman  I fully agree with you.  Yet the 30A breaker and the #12 wire exists.  Somebody did something...

@ChrisKnudsen, the home had 34 years of use and unknown number of owners. Many of which believe the BS hacks on youtube and watch enough home improvement shows to be dangerous.  Assuming the wrong breaker was installed by a professional is just barking up the most least likely tree.

Thanks for all of the replies SE is always the best:
BTW I'm in the USA/Louisiana.
I went back and checked the wires.
It seems the inspector was incorrect.
There are multiple 12 AWG and then a few larger for dryers etc.
All of the 12 AWG wires feed from 20 amp breakers.
There is ONE 30 amp breaker and it feeds to a 10 AWG.
I think the inspector was just mistaken I should have verified before posting.

Aha! So I suspect this "inspector" was not "County or city electrical inspector" but rather "generic home inspector". The problem with "generic home inspector" is that they are typically experts in only some parts of a house (and some of them experts in none!) - e.g., maybe they know structural but not electrical or electrical but not plumbing, etc. A little knowledge can be a dangerous thing.

The other answer is correct regarding the allowable ampacity of #12 wire (given some reasonable assumptions). I have a copy of the 1990 National Electrical Code that confirms this hasn't changed.
However, there is one aspect of this question (and the inspector's statement as quoted) that is missing:  The load.
Rather than simply saying "the breaker is too big for the wire", we must also look at the load attached to the circuit:  If the load is standard 15- or 20-amp receptacles, or standard lighting circuits not totalling more than 16 amps of continuous load, then yes, the breaker is oversized for the wire and for the load, and should be reduced to 20A.
If the load is (for example) a cooking appliance with 22 amps of continuous load, then the real issue is that the wire is undersized for the load and breaker and the wire should be replaced (most likely with AWG 10).

No, they haven't changed. That breaker should never have been installed on that circuit, and it should be replaced with a 20A breaker.

Unfortunately this is a common hack when people insist on turning on the kettle and toaster on the same circuit and get sick of having to keep turning the breaker back on.  Bigger breaker does not trip, even as flames are coming out of the wall.

The circuit sizing has always been #14 wire=15A...... #12=20A...... #10=30A.
So no, there wasn't an electrical code that allowed bigger breakers previously.  Most likely, this was irresponsible people being annoyed by breaker trips they caused by overloading the circuit, and defeating the overload protection. Lucky they didn't know about 60A breakers!
There is an exception for dedicated circuits to welder and motor loads e.g. your house's A/C unit. Those have overload protection on the motor itself (or welder transformer) which means the breaker is not needed for overload protection.  A somewhat larger breaker will provide reasonable short-circuit protection. Therefore NEC Article 230 allows the breaker to be enlarged to a degree, and 30A breaker on 20A wire would we well in spec of a typical motor, welder or A/C.
This is why you don't use random found circuits for EV charging, which run everything dead nuts at thermal limits for hours, the opposite of a very peaky motor/welder load.  I suspect this is also why welding people prefer the wacky, obsolete NEMA 10 family sockets - to keep non-peaky loads off their overbreakered circuits.

In addition to the other correct answers about a 30A breaker on 12 gauge wire being too big, when (not if, but when) you do replace the breaker with one of the correct size, also make sure it is a breaker type that is approved for your breaker panel, as not all breakers are approved for use in all panels.  The label inside the panel will list the acceptable breaker types that are correct.

One possibility, particularly if this is the circuit for an oven or cooktop, is:

Original circuit was 12 AWG with 20A breaker
New appliance installed that needed more power. Instructions said 30A, so the homeowner or a "handyman" (appliance companies will normally not touch a breaker panel (except to turn off during installation) for liability reasons, a professional electrician should never make such a mistake) replaced the breaker without knowing and/or caring about wire size

What to do now depends on the specifics, as noted in other answers. Either replace the cable/wire if you actually need 30A or replace the breaker if 20A is sufficient.
Note in particular though that there is a built-in safety in normal circuit sizes. A continuous load is supposed to get a circuit 125% of the load. For example, a typical clothes dryer or water heater will use between 19A and 23A on a 30A circuit. That fits with the maximum 24A of continuous load allowed. If you have a 23A load on a 20A breaker then you might find that it takes a long time for the breaker to actually trip, which is by design (see "trip curve"). But it is still a problem because over time the 12 AWG wire, depending on a bunch of details, may overheat enough times that it will eventually start to fail, leading to a fire, while 10 AWG wire on the same circuit (whether 20A occasional trip or 30A never trip) will do just fine.
Safety, particularly with electrical codes, is a multi-layer system. Break one layer and you're usually OK. But then you are sometimes very close to disaster.
Fix this before it burns your house down.
